# Knockoutjs: how can I make the input value added to a list also observable

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Not sure if I am phrasing this correctly.

I have an observableArray and I can add to that array from an input and also remove the list item. but if I modify the created item I lose the connection to the array. How can I keep the binding to the array?

[Fiddle Attached](https://jsfiddle.net/scorpion_rain/nc9p0utw/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="group-settings-container mt-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4><i class="fas fa-object-group"></i> Create Groups</h4>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control create-group-name" data-bind="value: groupItemToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' " placeholder="Enter group name" value="">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-primary add-group-btn" data-bind="click: addGroupItem, enable: groupItemToAdd().length > 0" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                      Add group</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="create-groups-container mb-4">
  <ul class="list-group create-group-list my-2" data-bind="foreach: allGroupItems">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control created-group-input" data-bind="value: $data">
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-danger remove-group-item-btn" data-bind="click: $parent.removeSelectedGroupItem" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                        Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end create groups container  -->

</div>
<!-- end group settings container -->
```

JS

```
 function ViewModel() {
 var self = this;
 self.groupItemToAdd = ko.observable("");
 self.allGroupItems = ko.observableArray([]);


 self.addGroupItem = function() {
 if ((self.groupItemToAdd() != "") &&     (self.allGroupItems.indexOf(self.groupItemToAdd()) < 0)) {
  self.allGroupItems.push(self.groupItemToAdd());
  }
  self.groupItemToAdd(""); // clear the input
 }

 self.removeSelectedGroupItem = function(index) {
 // self.allGroupItems.splice(index, 1);
// console.log(self.allGroupItems.splice(index, 1));
self.allGroupItems.remove(index);
}
}
// end ViewModel

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You have an `observableArray`. Which means, any changes to the array are tracked and updated. The items inside it are just strings. They are not `observables`. Any changes you make from the UI is not updated back to the view model. This behaviour is not limited to strings. The same thing applies if you have an `observableArray` of regular javascript object literals.

From the [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#key-point-an-observablearray-tracks-which-objects-are-in-the-array-not-the-state-of-those-objects):

> Simply putting an object into an `observableArray` doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves `observable`. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An `observableArray` just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

So, instead of adding strings to the `observableArray`, you can push an object with an `observable` property to the `observableArray`. Now the changes to `item` property are tracked. It's important to make the property an `observable`, otherwise you'll run into the same issue.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.groupItemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  self.allGroupItems = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.addGroupItem = function() {
    if (self.groupItemToAdd() && !self.allGroupItems().some(a => a.item() === self.groupItemToAdd())) {
      self.allGroupItems.push({
        item: ko.observable(self.groupItemToAdd())
      });
    }
    self.groupItemToAdd(""); // clear the input
  }

  self.removeSelectedGroupItem = function(index) {
    self.allGroupItems.remove(index);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="group-settings-container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h4><i class="fas fa-object-group"></i> Create Groups</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: groupItemToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' " placeholder="Enter group name">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary add-group-btn" data-bind="click: addGroupItem, enable: groupItemToAdd().length > 0" type="button">Add group</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <ul class="list-group create-group-list my-2" data-bind="foreach: allGroupItems">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control created-group-input" data-bind="value: item">
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-danger remove-group-item-btn" data-bind="click: $parent.removeSelectedGroupItem" type="button">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <span data-bind="text: allGroupItems().map(a => a.item())"></span>
```

Note:

- You need to change the input binding inside `foreach` from `$data` to `item` (observable property name)
- To check if a group item is already added, use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this: `self.allGroupItems().some(a => a.item() === self.groupItemToAdd())`
- The last `span` demonstrates that the observable is updated